# Bootstrap 3 gem on rails 3.2 form distorted

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, twitter-bootstrap

Using this gem: https://github.com/anjlab/bootstrap-rails

For some reason the forms are not working properly for me. There is not curves when the input is being used.

[image]

And I cannot add classes to it like 'form-inline' 
Not sure what the problem is. Anyone else facing this/have a solution?

After digging further, and deciding to trial and error, I got it working but have to manually input the classes for each form.

```
<%= text_field_tag :twitter_contact, nil, class: 'form-control'%>
```

Now i have this: 
[image]

Why is the gem not working automatically to do that itself? Am I missing something?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve? I don't quite sure what you're problem is.

Comment: @farleyknight the form is distorted (the appended part is not the same size). The border/box-shadow is distorted in comparison to the ones on the bootstrap site. And adding class: "form-inline" doesn't work for form_tag

Comment: Got it working. I had to manually inspect element every form that I liked and try to mimic it exactly (classes and ids) with my form.

Comment: <%= text_field_tag :twitter_contact, nil, class: 'form-control' %>       Why do I need the nil for it to work?

Comment: The 2nd argument is the default value of the field.

Comment: @farleyknight thanks! So I have to do everything manually... write all the divs and classes manually to have it looking like the BS docs. Or, is it actually like that and the gem just isn't working well for me?

Comment: Edited the post for more information

Comment: You can write you own helper methods that include this for you. For example `def my_text_field_tag(name, value); text_field_tag(name, value, class: 'form-control'); end` in your `ApplicationHelper` would give you something closer to what you're looking for.

Answer (score 1):

You can write you own helper methods that include this for you. For example

```
def my_text_field_tag(name, value)
  text_field_tag(name, value, class: 'form-control')
end
```

in your `ApplicationHelper` would give you something closer to what you're looking for.

The fact is that Ruby gem authors have to be careful injecting too much auto-magic into their code, as it actually conflicts with other Ruby gems. To a certain extent, you have to learn how Ruby works in order to get the full magic that you're looking for.

Comment: Ya that's an awesome suggestion!